# Android HttpUrlConnection response

Tags: php, android, httpurlconnection

I'm trying to send json data to a php script from my Android application with HttpUrlConnection, and get the response.

Android Code

```
private void sendPurchase(String SKU) throws IOException{       
    try{
        int pur_user = prefs.getInt("CONF_user", Integer.MIN_VALUE);
        URL url = new URL("http://www.example.com/includes/purchase.php");
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put("PUR_sku", SKU);
        jsonObject.put("PUR_user", pur_user);
        String json = jsonObject.toString();
        OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
        writer.write(json);
        writer.close();
        int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
        if(responseCode == 200) {
            InputStream content = connection.getInputStream();
            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content, "UTF-8"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){ sb.append(line).append("\n"); }
                Log.e("sendPruchase",sb.toString());
                content.close();
            } catch (Exception ex) { Log.e("sendPurchase", "Failed to parse JSON due to: " + ex); } finally { connection.disconnect(); }
        } else { Log.e("sendPurchase", "Server responded with status code: " + responseCode); }
    } catch(Exception ex) { Log.e("sendPurchase", "Failed to send HTTP POST request due to: " + ex); }
}
```

And the PHP script

```
<? 
$auth=0;
require('./connexion.php');
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
//$data = '{"PUR_sku":"singleone","PUR_user":"3"}';
$json = json_decode($data,true);
/* Some database stuff ... */
echo "Retour ".print_r($json)." et ".$json['PUR_sku']." et ".$json['PUR_user'];
?>
```

My code is about purchasing an item, consume it and send new value to my database on a web server. The purchase & consume are ok, but i can't send the values to the web server. 
And again, when i execute the php script alone in a web browser, replacing first $data line by the second one (see script), everything is ok.
Note that i have another similar code to register user to GCM, and that code works fine.

```
06-25 14:07:12.968: D/IabHelper(21833): Successfully consumed sku: singleconf
06-25 14:07:12.968: D/IabHelper(21833): Ending async operation: consume
06-25 14:07:12.979: D/CONSUME(21833): Consumption finished. Purchase: PurchaseInfo(type:inapp):{"orderId":"12999763169054705758.1353445524837889","packageName":"com.*.*","productId":"singleconf","purchaseTime":1435234296875,"purchaseState":0,"purchaseToken":"bohbcbiigcbidfficbikebnk.AO-J1OzuQ_SsNTG1h9MtUvbaPc3PeN9nBHG-qBOE82ao1rTDFNrgA7tYQcMdECxCVFrrZEn_QifQ28OcIupyesZI-5cjDILFODYpBEaeqMfE0wCAeMFkJLfNUK_TsKPMj7F2sBDdgOYx"}, result: IabResult: Successful consume of sku singleconf (response: 0:OK)
06-25 14:07:12.979: D/CONSUME(21833): You bought & consumed a single conf
06-25 14:07:12.979: D/CONSUME(21833): End consumption flow.
06-25 14:07:12.979: E/Purchase Background(21833): Inside doInBackground
06-25 14:07:12.979: E/sendPurchase(21833): Failed to send HTTP POST request due to: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Thanks for any idea !

Comment: Could you please add `e.printStackTrace()` to the last `catch` clause? And then add the whole stack trace after running your app again

Comment: 06-25 14:07:12.979: E/sendPurchase(21833): Failed to send HTTP POST request due to: java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: @AnoopM it's just his custom exception message, it doesn't say anything about where NPE took place.

Comment: Can you show me `SKU` String

Comment: I added e.printStackTrace() and changed the way the sendPurchase method is called (in order to avoid all the purchase flow) and now i get a an error "Server responded with status code: 500" ...

Answer (score -1):

**Android Side:**

```
private void sendPurchase(String SKU) {

    /** 
     * Initialize All Variables
     */

    httpPost = new HttpPost(url.toString());

    pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    jsonObject.put("PUR_sku", SKU);
    jsonObject.put("PUR_user", pur_user);

    pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data", jsonObject.toString()));

    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs,HTTP.UTF_8));

    response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

    entity = response.getEntity();
    is = entity.getContent();

    /* Convert response to string */
    result = getResult(is);

    Log.d(TAG, "Response of Send Result : " + result);
}
```

**PHP Side:**

```
$data = json_decode($this->input->post('data'), true);

/** Your Process **/
```

May it will helps you.

Comment: Something went wrong, i get this error "Failed to send HTTP POST request due to: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse cannot be cast to java.io.InputStream"

Comment: I corrected this issue, but the real problem seems to come from the PHP side. [I posted a new question here if you want to take a look](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31297639/php-script-error-when-called-from-android-httpclient/31298070#31298070)